# Is it possible to get relation in Views to Commerce products?

Tags: views, commerce

I made View by Taxonomy term.
Using Relations I got Content which has this Taxonomy term.

Now I want to see couple of Commerce fields (SKU and Price) which are referenced from Content type.
Is it possible from Taxonomy View go to Content (I have already done it) and then to Commerce fields from Content?

Comment: Yes you use the product relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Make the relationship with commerce product then you will see the related fields in fields list.